# Solve complex equation $\left(\frac{8}{z^3}\right) - i = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, cubics

from $$(a^3 + b^3) = (a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$$
I have $${(2/z)}^3 + i^3 =0$$
I have $$\left(\frac{2}{z} + i\right)\left(\left(\frac{2}{z}\right)^2-(2/z)(i)-1)\right) = 0$$
i.e.$ \left(\frac{2}{z}\right)+i = 0 $ or $ \left(\left(\frac{2}{z}\right)^2-(\frac{2}{z})(i)-1\right) = 0$
......
but I'm not sure that is the correct answer;
help me please. 
Thank you.

Comment: If this had been a real equation, say $\frac8{x^3}-1=0$, how would you have solved it? It's a lot easier that what you have done here. And the complex numbers aren't so different from the reals, so you can solve your equation in basically the same way.

Comment: Well, it still seems like you didn't fully solve the problem. The path is now split into two roads : $\left( \frac{2}{z}\right) + 1 =0$ and $\left( \frac{2}{z} \right)^2 + (\frac{2}{z})i -1 = 0$. Analyse these and then report back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\dfrac8{z^3}=i\implies z^3=\dfrac8i=-8i$.

Since $2^3=8$ and $i^3=-i$, it is apparent that $z=2i, 2i\omega$, or $2i\omega^2$,

where $\omega$ is a primitive cube root of $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $i^{3} = -i$

Then $(\frac{2}{z})^{3} + i^{3} = 0 \iff (\frac{2}{z})^{3} - i = 0 \iff z^{3} = -2^{3}i = -8i $

Then the solutions are $z_{1} = 2i,  z_{2} = 2e^{i\frac{2\pi }{3}}i, z_{3} = 2e^{i \frac{4\pi }{3}}i$

Comment: $\left(\dfrac2x\right)^3-i=0\iff z^3=2^3\color{red}/i=\color{red}-8i,$ so solutions are $\color{red}+2i...$

Comment: Thank you Tanner !!!